# Upload file directly to S3 without need to use forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

For my Rails application, I download a bunch of files from a remote URL to my application. I would like to directly upload them to Amazon S3, without needing a form to do the upload, since I will temporarily cache the file I downloaded on the EC2 instance. 
I would also like to retain the links to the files I uploaded so I can download them later.

I am essentially reposting the files I downloaded.

I looked around, but most of the solution seem to involve form uploading to S3 with a user.

Is there s direct upload solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can upload directly to S3 using the [AWS SDK for Ruby](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/). The easiest way is:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-west-2')
obj = s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('key')
obj.upload_file('/path/to/source/file')
```

Or you can find a couple other options [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [EvaporateJS](https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS) to achieve this. You can also take advantage of sending ajax request to update file name to the database after each file upload. Though javascript exposes few details your bucket is not vulnerable to hack as S3 service provide a bucket policy.

Just set the `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` to `<AllowedOrigin>specificwebsite.com</AllowedOrigin>` in production mode.